# Deployment Failed Error while Creating VM on Azure

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

Free Trail subsription
VM creation fails with the following error:

```
"status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "OperationFailed",
        "message": "The operation '901702b29b2eae5cbd6d3b6770eac08d' failed: 'Allocation failed. Please retry later, try reducing the VM size or number of role instances, or try deploying to a different region.'."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors) describes the possible error codes.

Looks like it is about the VM size.
I could not find along the VM setting the possibility of setting the VM size.
I could only select from predefine configurations. I chose the smallest. 28G with local SSD 56G. I'm not sure what the difference between these two.

Please advise

Comment: which VM size in what region did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after switching to few other region(s) managed to create the vm. Probably something with the free trail limitations